# Наследование Angular 2 и Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2, typescript

Есть два компонента, в которых существуют две идентичные функции. Исходя из принципов ООП, логичнее всего поместить эти функции в отдельный класс, а затем компонентам наследоваться от этого класса.

Вопрос в том, как это сделать так, чтоб потом другие люди восприняли этот код нормально. То есть, как оформить и в какую папку поместить новый класс и, в целом, используется ли подобный подход относительно Angular`a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример из статьи:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2

можно сделать папку abstract для абстрактных компонентов и потор разделить по фича папкам

еще конечно оф. документация:
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SimplePaginationComponent } from './simple-pagination.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-pagination',
  template: `
    <a (click)="previousPage()" [class.disabled]="!hasPrevious()" 
      href="javascript:void(0)">
      ««
    </a> 
    <span>{{ page }} / {{ pageCount }}</span>
    <a (click)="nextPage()" [class.disabled]="!hasNext()"
      href="javascript:void(0)" >
      »»
    </a>
  `
})
export class MyPaginationComponent extends SimplePaginationComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ предыдущего автора - можно так же сделать интерфейс и указать какие свойства и методы необходимо реализовать (допустим может различаться реализацию функции MySomeFunction() в некоторых компонентах). 
[Допустим вот как тут](https://metanit.com/web/typescript/3.3.php)

Это может пригодится, если есть несколько компонентов, которые выполняют один и тот же метод, но реализация может отличаться. 
Ну а если необходимо именно сохранить реализацию метода от класса-родителя, тогда наследование с помощью extends.